# Setup file cannot be installed on other computers

Tags: python, tkinter

I created an installer file using nsis. After running the programme on my system, it worked flawlessly but when installed on third party system, it complained on launching the app.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Classify.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "tkinter\_init_.py", line 2109, in wm_iconbitmap
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "D:\Users\Engr M2J\Documents\GitHub\HAM1000-Image-Classifier\logo.ico" not defined
```

I know this is where the error is coming from;

```
  root.title("HAM10000 Image Classifier by Engr. Sule Muhammed Abba- BookNowNow Code version 1.1.0")
root.iconbitmap(r'D:\Users\Engr M2J\Documents\GitHub\HAM1000-Image-Classifier\logo.ico')
```

it is actually referencing my computer path instead of it to be relative. This is the only way I could get the icon to load by using it direct path. whenever I use the below code, I get the error that follows;

```
 root.iconbitmap('logo.ico')
```

I get this error

```
 return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "logo.ico" not defined
```

Please assist

Comment: For the relative path case, did you put the icon file in the same folder with the script?

Comment: The relative path that I gave to my system is working fine but when I create the executable, the software will not work on another system as it will reference the icon to my system directory which is not available on that system. Hence my software can only be used on my system. I have found a way to solve it which I will share momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps taken to solve the problem.

1. I printed the working directory.

   ```
   print(getcwd())
   ```
2. I then copied all code files to this directory
3. By doing this, I was able to load the icon using

   ```
   root.iconbitmap(r'logo.ico')
   ```
4. My new software now runs seamlessly on different systems without any complain.
5. Any better solution is welcome but this will work perfectly.